# YouTube API already watched time of video

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to get already watched time of YouTube video.

Example:

[image: YouTube thumbnail with progress]

It is visible in UI, so it must be possible to get somehow. I checked https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos and https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search, but this info doesn't seems to be at any of those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API endpoint which returns how far along a user is in watching a video.  The YouTube api is mostly a file store for videos it doesn't expose information about user progress in a video.